# How to create order with extra baggage/seat

Tags: amadeus

I'm using self-service APIs, and I already get the extra baggage information from the flight offer price API, such as price, quantity , weight etc. But how to create order by adding the extra baggage? Do you have an exemple about this scenario?

Same question for seat. Once I get the seat map of flight offer, is it possible to create order by selecting available seat ? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Add baggage information

You first need to include the `include=bags` parameter in the path of Flight Offers Price API to get the bags information:

https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/shopping/flight-offers/pricing?include=bags

As you mentioned you get that information so I suppose you have done this step already.

Now the bag catalog is be returned on the API response providing the price and quantity/weight and looks like:

```
"bags": {
      "1": {
        "quantity": 1,
        "name": "CHECKED_BAG",
        "price": {
          "amount": "30.00",
          "currencyCode": "EUR"
        }
```

Once you have selected the bag you want, you can fill in the `chargeableCheckedBags` part either the quantity or the weight (depending of what the airline you use) in the travelerPricings/fareDetailsBySegment/additionalServices and you add the bag per flight segment like the example below:

```
"fareDetailsBySegment": [
    {
        "segmentId": "1",
        "cabin": "ECONOMY",
        "fareBasis": "TNOBAGD",
        "brandedFare": "GOLIGHT",
        "class": "T",
        "includedCheckedBags": {
            "quantity": 0
        },
        "additionalServices": {
            "chargeableCheckedBags": {
                "quantity": 1
            }
        }
    }
]
```

### Select available seats with SeatMap API

You can go through this [guide](https://developers.amadeus.com/blog/seat-selection-amadeus-seat-map-api) which contains examples and all the details for seat selection.

Comment: Hi anna how to include baggages to segments if bookableByItinerary is false