# extra bag information is missing in the flight offer price response

Tags: amadeus

I'm testing self-service APIs. I wonder if this is a bug:

1. I make a search request, and the response contains the extra bag information in the `flight-offer/price/additionalServices`
2. Then I make the offer price request by adding `include=bags` parameter in the path of Flight Offers Price API.

However there is no any bags information in the response, neither in the `offer/price/additionalServices`, nor in the `included/`.

3. I still try to create order by adding the extra bag. So I use the extra bag information that I got at step 1 (search response). And the order is created successfully.

It seems that the extra bag information is missing in step 2 (response of flight offer price), is it a bug?

Here is an example of my test to reproduce the issue:

search request

```
{
  "currencyCode": "EUR",
  "originDestinations": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "originLocationCode": "PAR",
      "destinationLocationCode": "NYC",
      "departureDateTimeRange": {
        "date": "2020-08-20",
        "time": "10:00:00"
      }
    }
  ],
  "travelers": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "travelerType": "ADULT"
    }
  ],
  "sources": [
    "GDS"
  ],
  "searchCriteria": {
    "maxFlightOffers": 3
  }
}
```

Then I select the second offer in the response to make a offer price request using `include=bags` parameter

```
 {
      "type": "flight-offer",
      "id": "2",
      "source": "GDS",
      "instantTicketingRequired": false,
      "nonHomogeneous": false,
      "oneWay": false,
      "lastTicketingDate": "2020-08-13",
      "numberOfBookableSeats": 8,
      "itineraries": [
        {
          "duration": "PT8H15M",
          "segments": [
            {
              "departure": {
                "iataCode": "ORY",
                "terminal": "4",
                "at": "2020-08-20T19:45:00"
              },
              "arrival": {
                "iataCode": "EWR",
                "terminal": "B",
                "at": "2020-08-20T22:00:00"
              },
              "carrierCode": "TX",
              "number": "6720",
              "aircraft": {
                "code": "359"
              },
              "operating": {
                "carrierCode": "BF"
              },
              "duration": "PT8H15M",
              "id": "3",
              "numberOfStops": 0,
              "blacklistedInEU": false
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "price": {
        "currency": "EUR",
        "total": "149.44",
        "base": "41.00",
        "fees": [
          {
            "amount": "0.00",
            "type": "SUPPLIER"
          },
          {
            "amount": "0.00",
            "type": "TICKETING"
          }
        ],
        "grandTotal": "149.44",
        "additionalServices": [
          {
            "amount": "70.00",
            "type": "CHECKED_BAGS"
          }
        ]
      },
      "pricingOptions": {
        "fareType": [
          "PUBLISHED"
        ],
        "includedCheckedBagsOnly": false
      },
      "validatingAirlineCodes": [
        "TX"
      ],
      "travelerPricings": [
        {
          "travelerId": "1",
          "fareOption": "STANDARD",
          "travelerType": "ADULT",
          "price": {
            "currency": "EUR",
            "total": "149.44",
            "base": "41.00"
          },
          "fareDetailsBySegment": [
            {
              "segmentId": "3",
              "cabin": "ECONOMY",
              "fareBasis": "ULBCOWFR",
              "brandedFare": "EBASIC",
              "class": "U",
              "includedCheckedBags": {
                "quantity": 0
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
 }
```

There is no extra bag in the response.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Xin, I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63195597) is related to your question.

Comment: @alnacle thanks. That's also my question, I asked "how to add extra bag when creating order" firstly. But here, I think there is a bug potentially about the offer price API. So I ask an additional question to confirm it

Comment: Hi @Xin, we have been investigating this issue and we believe it could be a bug. I will keep you posted. Thanks for your patience!